# Angular Material Datepicker openStream and closeStream

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datepicker, angular-material

Regarding to the official docs of angular material the datepicker component provides two output's that get emit if the datepicker is opened (`openedStream`) or closed (`closedStream`) ([datepicker-api](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)).

If I open and close the datepicker I get nothing out of those eventsand my `<div>{{ message }}</div>` remains empty and shows no value.

My actual Setup

```js
export class NoteCreateComponent {
  public message = "";
  
  constructor(){}
  
  toggleDatePicker(picker){
      picker.open();
  }
}
```

```html
<div>{{ message }}</div>
<button (click)="toggleDatePicker(picker)" mat-icon-button>
<mat-datepicker 
    (openedStream)="message=$event"
    (closedStream)="message=$event" #picker>
</mat-datepicker>
```

*Expected result would either I open or close the datepicker (not only by clicking a button) I get a feedback.*

Comment: same issue here

Comment: same issue, also with `(monthSelected)`. It doesn't look like the @Output is emitting values, unless I emit it manually using a @ViewChild.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<mat-datepicker 
(opened)="streamOpened()" 
(closed)="streamClosed()" #picker> 
</mat-datepicker>
```

You should not use openedStream and closedStream event name because they are internal field names of DatePicker component. Use `opened` and `closed`. Look at [MatDatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker) documetation:

```
@Output('closed') closedStream: EventEmitter<void>
@Output('opened') openedStream: EventEmitter<void>
```

Comment: Hi ! Maybe you can give us some more context on your answer :)

Comment: Yes, you should give more context to an answer rather than just dropping a block of code that the OP or future readers may not understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some explanation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20959452)

Comment: @BruceWayne No links in this answer. However, Umais, while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Umais is right. You should not use openedStream and  closedStream event name because they are internal field names of DatePicker component. Use `opened` and `closed`. Look at [DatePicker documetation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker) : `@Output('closed') closedStream: EventEmitter<void>` and `@Output('opened')
openedStream: EventEmitter<void>`

Answer (score -1):

since openedStream and closedStream not emitting values, you cannot get $event value and set it to message variable.

Can you try this code:

```
<div>{{ message }}</div>
<button (click)="toggleDatePicker(picker)" mat-icon-button>
<mat-datepicker 
    (openedStream)="streamOpened()" 
    (closedStream)="streamClosed()" #picker>
</mat-datepicker>
```

in .ts file

```
...
streamOpened() {
   this.message = 'Stream Opened';
}

streamClosed() {
   this.message = 'Stream Closed';
}
...
```

Comment: I tried this solution before asking this question, and now i tried it with the exact same syntax. Nothing happens. I don't get a console.log("open") repsonse wich I added in the function. Nothing

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is the input attribute of [opened]

```
<mat-datepicker 
    #planDatepicker
    [opened]="open()">
```

[angular datepicker docs](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
<input 
        type="hidden"
        id="selectedDateInput"
        #selectedDateInput
        [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker"
        [min]="minDate"
        [max]="maxDate"
        (dateChange)="dateUpdated(myDatepicker, this)">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker 
        (nextClicked)="nextClicked(myDatepicker, $event, this)" 
        (previousClicked)="previousClicked(myDatepicker, $event, this)"
        (selectedChanged)="getMonth(myDatepicker, $event, this)"
        (opened)="calIsOpened(this)">
      </mat-datepicker>
```